# Fix backspace in vim + tmux + tcsh + konsole

Tags: vim, tmux, tcsh, backspace, konsole

My shell is tcsh. I'm using vim in tmux with konsole. When I type backspace in insert mode it inserts `^?`. This only happens in tmux. In konsole settings the backspace input is set to `\b`. I try changing it to `\x8` and there is no change. `fixdel` doesn't help, `set bs=2` in `.vimrc` doesn't work. I don't use `setty` anywhere, nor do I change the tmux keybindings. Any help? Please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try `:set backspace=indent,eol,start`. Then, check your backspace. If this works, just put this line in your vimrc.

This works for me with Vim+tmux; I don't use Konsole or tcsh, so I can't confirm that those won't break it, but I'd be very surprised if those did.

Comment: It didn't work by itself, but adding 
```noremap! <C-?> <C-h>
set backspace=indent,eol,start```
to ```.vimrc``` worked. This seems like such a hack. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. What makes this inelegant? It's a simple option in your vimrc that removes the unwanted effect.

Comment: Just `noremap! <C-?> <C-h>` worked for me.
I use vim + tmux + tcsh combination